# How to query list of user IDS in a Amazon Redshift table based on distance from a specific latitude/longitude?

Tags: mysql, sql, amazon-redshift

Currently using:

```
SELECT
uid,lat,long,
(
    6371 *
    acos(
        cos( radians( value ) ) *
        cos( radians( lat ) ) *
        cos(
            radians( long ) - radians( value )
        ) +
        sin(radians(value)) *
        sin(radians(lat))
    )
) as distance
FROM
    table name
WHERE
    lat IS NOT Null AND long IS NOT Null
HAVING
    distance < 25
ORDER BY
    distance
LIMIT
    25;
```

Comment: @Serg Beautiful edit, I've never seen haversine/great circle not look ugly.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Should be attributed to OP. I Just added an ident,  ctl/K. Upvoting for the beautiful acos.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Which is I like to use a UDF for this! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30259410/query-to-calculate-sum-of-distance-longitude-latitude-in-consecutive-rows-in

Comment: @Strawberry UDF spells `UGH` if you change two of the letters :-)

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I suppose mine is really a Stored Function, which is less efficient than a UDF - but it makes the end query easier to read and I don't know C.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MySQL sort of overloaded the `HAVING` clause to allow it to be used as a `WHERE` clause with aliases available.  While Redshift does not have this feature, you could first calculate the distance in a CTE or subquery, and then use the computed distance field, to avoid repeating the distance calculation in the `WHERE` clause:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT
        uid,
        lat,
        long,
        (
            6371 *
            acos(
                cos( radians( value ) ) *
                cos( radians( lat ) ) *
                cos(
                    radians( long ) - radians( value )
                ) +
                sin(radians(value)) *
                sin(radians(lat))
            )
        ) AS distance
    FROM yourTable
    WHERE
        lat IS NOT Null AND
        long IS NOT Null
)

SELECT    
    t.uid,
    t.lat,
    t.long
FROM cte t
WHERE t.distance < 25
ORDER BY t.distance
LIMIT 25;
```

If your version of Redshift does not support CTE or you don't want to use one, then just place the above CTE into a subquery.

Comment: This seems to return duplicate values on latitude and longitude columns on different user ids as well as distance, checking if there is issue in DB for different uids  with same lat/long.

Comment: @NeilNandi Then this is a different issue than what you asked in your question.  I have directly answered your original question.

Comment: Yes. Thanks for the solution. Seems to be working fine @Tim

Answer (score 0):

I've created a UDF for myself:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.f_distance(lat1 double precision, lon1 double precision, lat2 double precision, lon2 double precision)
RETURNS double precision
IMMUTABLE AS $$
    import math
    if lat1==None or lat2==None or lon1==None or lon2==None:
        return None
    if lat1==lat2 and lon1==lon2:
        return 0
    else:
        return (6371*math.acos(
               math.cos(math.radians(lat1))*math.cos(math.radians(lat2))*math.cos(math.radians(lon2)-math.radians(lon1))+
               math.sin(math.radians(lat1))*math.sin(math.radians(lat2))
            )
        )
$$ LANGUAGE plpythonu;
```

so it can be used directly like this:

```
SELECT uid,lat,long,f_distance(search_lat,search_long,lat,long) as distance
FROM your_table
WHERE f_distance(search_lat,search_long,lat,long)<25
ORDER BY 4
LIMIT 25
```